# Cannot install PDO on CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, centos

I know there is several instances of this question throughout stackoverflow but I am not finding a solution.

I am running CentOS with Apache and PHP 5.3

A .php script is giving me this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in ...
```

I ran `phpinfo();` and the only place "pdo" exists on the page is in the "Configure Command"  `'--disable-pdo'` line.

I attempted `#yum install php-pdo` but no packages exist.

I also attempted `#pecl install pdo` and i get these errors at the end:

```
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function 'pdo_stmt_instantiate':
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:410: error: 'zval' has no member named 'refcount'
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:411: error: 'zval' has no member named 'is_ref'
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function 'pdo_stmt_construct':
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:435: error: 'zend_fcall_info' has no member named 'object_pp'
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:458: error: 'zend_fcall_info_cache' has no member named 'object_pp'
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function 'zim_PDO_setAttribute':
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:752: error: 'zval' has no member named 'refcount'
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function 'zim_PDO_getAttribute':
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:818: error: 'zval' has no member named 'refcount'
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c: In function 'pdo_hash_methods':
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1122: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/root/tmp/pear/PDO/pdo_dbh.c:1126: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [pdo_dbh.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Then on the php.net doc it basically says the package comes standard in php installations since PHP 5.1.

I added the line `extension=pdo.so` to php.ini and restarted Apache and the problem persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: `php-pdo` is the correct name of the package for CentOS. Does it show up if you do `yum search php-pdo`?

Comment: the only results i get for yum search pdo are a bunch of "casenoupdown" packages. i also ran yum clean all and yum update recently

Comment: maybe this is my problem http://serverfault.com/questions/511779/cant-install-php-pdo

Comment: Do `yum repolist` -- do you get `updates` in the output?

Comment: updates         CentOS-6 - Updates

Comment: Maybe the mirror you're using is borked? The `yum repolist` command will tell you which one you're currently using. Edit your `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf` and add a line `exclude=whatever` to it, where `whatever` is the mirror's domain name. Then do `yum install php-pdo` again.

Comment: Or you could just manually download the RPM yourself from `http://mirror.rackspace.com/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/` (or whatever path matches your version) and then install it with `rpm -i <file>`

Comment: I have done all suggestions with no success. I tried using Easy Apache trhough WHM and it could complete with some errors about my software management software being corrupt (yum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have had a similar issue. I am using codeigniter and was getting a "pdo_mysql.so not found" error and tried everything to fix it. I must of searched thru the first 10 pages of google search results for multiple queries. I found tons of people with the same problems but for some reason none of them had an answer/fix. Thru all this reading I learned that "***PDO and the PDO_SQLITE driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0.***" This got me thinking, "Perhaps I should **remove the extension=pdo_mysql.so and pdo.so lines from my php.ini**!" I figured php was trying to load an extension that was no longer there since it comes built in now. Sure enough, solved all my php error mess.

> PHP 5.4.31 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2014 10:38:48)
>   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>   Server version: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix)
>   Server built:   Aug 19 2014 10:33:30
>   Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.26.5 rev9999

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you're missing the PHP_PDO package. Try to find the PDO package by running the command bellow:

```
 # rpm -qa| grep "pdo"
```

Mine shows php53u-pdo-5.3.26-1.ius.el5

If you are using php 5.3 then try

```
# yum install php53u-pdo
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is too late for the answer, but I'll post if someone finds this error.

First, I had installed php-pdo in Centos 7 with yum. I viewed phpinfo and it shows the pdo extension but not pdo-mysql.

So, If you then installs php-mysql (yum install php-mysql) it will install automatically the pdo-mysql extension.